# MySQL for Excel connection failed

Tags: mysql, excel, authentication, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I am running MySQL on Windows 10, I have fresh install of MySQL for windows on my Local Machine (version 8.0.11) Full install, using a development machine config. I can log into my server on the MySQL Workbench. I have installed the MySQL for Excel addon. I have not added any Table to the Database yet, I was planning on adding them through Excel.

When I click on the MySQL for Excel tab in Excel and attempt to connect as root to my local instance, it fails.

The error message

> Authentication method 'caching_sha2_password' not supported by any of the available plugin.

Reading the documentation for this release, it seems that the plugin should be automatically included in the download.

Thanks for any help you guys can give.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go To Search type --> MySQL Installer - Community then enter.
   then dialog box open press yes.
2. Select "Reconfigure" over the mysql server;
3. In Authentication Method tab, select "Use Legacy Authentication Method"

Comment: Do I have to create a new connection on the workbench?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem as well.

This way may fix your problem:

1. Executing the install file;
2. Select "Reconfigure" over the mysql server;
3. In Authentication Method tab, select "Use Legacy Authentication Method"

Answer (score 0):

## MySQL 8

In  MySQL 8.0.4 they changed the hashing algorithm from `mysql_native_password` to `caching_sha2_password` ( SHA-256 ).  The MySQL plugin, even installed with MySQL 8 as a bundle, won't work with  SHA-256.  Therefore we need to create a user with the `mysql_native_password`, grant permissions, and flush privileges.

A final point, MySQL8 usernames are not unique, and having two users with the same username that are authorized to access the overlapping resource ( using grant on an individual not using the new role functionality ) is possible in ways it wasn't before.

> MySQL is owned by Oracle, and this is more similar to how Oracle 12c database works.  At first glance it seems cumbersome, but the model has proven better in my opinion.

## Solution

Just create a user specifically for the purpose of connecting over your plugin.  Run the following commands

```
CREATE USER 'excel_plugin_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'P@ssw0rd1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'excel_plugin_user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then use excel_plugin_user for all your MySQL Excel plugin connections.  This is just a minimum viable workaround, but it's not necessarily best practice.

> I usually create an imp tablespace for this user and import all data to that tablespace (set as default or it wont work), only from localhost, and generally would create a role that bit my relational data.  However, I think a true DBA would set up public/private keys ( also supported )

## Anti-Pattern

You could also just add the following line to your my.cnf file ( or whatever Windows calls it )

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password
```

> There is a command line flag you can set if you want it to be session dependent.  I don't know which takes precedence